# Using azure maps fuzzy search returns duplicate results

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I'm building a smart search that will be used to lookup the Town/City of the user using Azure Maps Address Fuzzy Search API.

For some reason I'm getting duplicate results where the Municipality and MunicipalitySubdivision are reversed:

[image]

[image]

This is when using the following:

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?subscription-key=<<KEY_HERE>>&api-version=1.0&query=Walsall%20Birmingham&typeahead=false&limit=50&countrySet=gb&idxSet=GEO
```

I'm interested in storing the following:
Country
Municipality
MunicipalitySubdivision
Latitude
Longitude

I don't want to display street level data, purely GEO (town, city etc).

Is there a setting which I'm missing for the fuzzy search, or would I be better off using one of the other search services?

Comment: Just checking on this, did you get any resolution on this issue? Do you still need help regarding this query?

Comment: @SatishBoddu-MSFT I never found a resolution. I'm assuming it's a data issue within azure maps. Walsall is a town, Birmingham is a city. I can't see why Birmingham would be listed as a subdivision of Birmingham.